# Unable to authenticate az rest API call noninteractively in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-service-principal

I am attempting to automate **Azure DevOps PAT** rotation with a powershell script getting executed in a pipeline. As long as I have run az login in my powershell session, my script works as expected and is able to successfully call the [Pats endpoints detailed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0).

To run it in a pipeline, I am using the Azure CLI task with a service connection for the Azure subscription parameter. I had assumed that this essentially does the 'az login' for you using the service connection to then run the script within.

This is what the pipeline task looks like:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Rotate PAT
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.service_connection }}
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: scriptPath
    scriptPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/scripts/AzureDevOpsPatRotation.ps1
    arguments: '-tokenName "${{ parameters.token_name }}" -varGroupName "${{ parameters.variable_group_name }}" -varName "${{ parameters.variable_name }}" -pat "${{ parameters.pat }}"'
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    failOnStandardError: true
```

However when running the pipeline, I get a couple different errors. First is an html error response:

```
ERROR: (ï»¿<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Access Denied: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 needs the following permission(s) on the resource Subjects to perform this action: Read by public identifier</title>
    <style type="text/css">html {
    height: 100%;
}

...

<div class="error-info">
    <div class="title">500 - Something went wrong!</div>
    <div class="details">We've encountered an error and cannot fulfill this request. We will trace the error and get a fix out soon.</div>
    <div class="reference-data">
      <div>2/21/2023 12:44:31 AM (UTC)</div>
      <div>67cec8df-d6be-4998-a726-5e19c7f091d4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="action-container">
      <a class="action" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=328778">
        <span>Contact support</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Second is a json console error:

```
ERROR: ({"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as ********-****-****-****-************\\********-****-****-****-************\\********-****-****-****-************ in a web browser to enable access to the service.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"UnauthorizedRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000})
Interactive authentication is needed. Please run:
az logout
az login
ERROR: argument --value: expected one argument
```

I looked up the guid that the second error is referencing and it appears to be the objectID of the service principal used in the service connection.

I know the error is plainly saying that an interactive auth is needed, but my question is if there is a way around this to make this noninteractive such that PAT rotation can be automated in a pipeline. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would first try and resolve this one _needs the following permission(s) on the resource Subjects to perform this action: Read by public identifier_ it might resolve the second error

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid do you have any idea what that could mean?

Comment: Yes. I imagine your service connection is missing "Read by public identifier" rights in whatever you are trying to access. It may help if you post the powershell code

Comment: So the service principal behind your service connection needs to be granted some kind of right within DevOps

Comment: This may shed some light on the authorization required https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops#example-get-started-with-a-python-flask-quickstart-application

Answer (score 0):

`azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.service_connection }}` gives you a SPN, and the support of SPN with Azure DevOps is releasd on march 2023, but I haven't tested it yet. Instead you could use old method by using `$(System.AccessToken)` to set it as the Bearer token header when calling with `az rest`. Below is a bash script example, powershell should be similar

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Az rest
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.service_connection }}
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az rest \
          --headers "Authorization=Bearer $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" \
          --resource 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798 \
          --url <url>
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

BTW, I've a big question if `${{ parameters.service_connection }}` works here, it needs to be specified during the compiling time. To test, could you please run any other standard azcli (not az rest) command to query an azure resource for example, does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

Service principal is not allowed to perform such operation. You need a proper AAD user to do this. You can just login in az cli in pipeline with something like(you can store username and password in Key Vault and MFA must be disabled for this user):

```
az login -u <username> -p <password>
```

#### More details

The reason you are getting `Read by public identifier` error is due to the fact that the service connection has no access to your Azure Devops orgnization. You can resolve this by adding service principal of the app registration representing the service connection to your Azure Devops organization(yes, you can do that.) And you will have something like this:
[image]

But soon you will end up with another error in the pipeline which makes more sense:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Service principals are not allowed to perform this  action.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.InvalidAccessException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server",
    "typeKey": "InvalidAccessException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```